# GCC considers int pointers unaligned on ARM

Tags: c, gcc, arm, memory-alignment

I have the following test program:

```
#include <string.h>
int q(int *p) {
    int x;
    memcpy(&x,p,sizeof(int));
    x+=12;
    memcpy(p,&x,sizeof(int));
    return p[0];
}
```

When I compile this using GCC 4.7.2 for arm-linux-gnueabihf, the compiler suspects that the pointer accesses may be unaligned, annotating the loads and stores in the assembly output, for example:

```
    ldr     r0, [r0, #0]    @ unaligned
```

If I compile with `-mno-unaligned-access`, the compiler does not emit direct loads and stores at all but calls the library `memcpy` instead. But in fact, the pointers in this case should never be unaligned. Is this an overlook in gcc, or am I mistaken?

Comment: please post full disassembly of the compiled code.

Comment: It does a better job with `int q(int *restrict p) { p[0]+=12; return p[0];}`.  `mov r3,r0`, `ldr r0,[r0]`,`add r0,r0,#12`,`str r0,[r3]`, `blx`.  Why do you want to code this?  It is true that it should be aligned.  As others have noted, you are confusing it with `memcpy()`.  At the very least,  `x = p[0];` seems semi-sane.  Why are you using `memcpy()` as an assignment?  The next person will come along and proclaim that `*p` is a byte-swapped version.  Maybe the larger problem will help?

Comment: The point of using `memcpy` is to be compatible with strict-aliasing rules. The given `int *` pointer may be derived from a pointer to an another type.

Comment: @Juho Well, that is exactly the reason that `gcc` is generating `memcpy`, because if `int*p` is a `char*p` in disguise then it may not be aligned at all. So I'm not even sure the compiler could decide at all (apart from whole program analysis), that `int*p` is aligned. And considering your motivation `gcc` is right.

Comment: If a pointer is cast to `int*`, it is a promise to the compiler that the result is properly aligned. The compiler is not required to support unaligned access through `int*`, gcc, for example, has packed structs for that.

Comment: @Juho Exactly, I had to look it up in the standard and I've added the relevant clause to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are few things better optimized in C compilers than loads and stores of `int` values, which are by design a natural size for the machine.

Write the function as

```
int q(int *p) {
    return *p += 12;
}
```

which avoids two calls to a library routine which you are otherwise counting on the optimizer to inline and reduce to a simple load and store, and expresses the intent of modifying the integer-value parameter in-place and returning the result.

Using `memcpy` to assign integers obfuscates the intent.

If this question is a result of reducing a larger problem to a least size example of the confusion, then my implementation may not help directly. But even if the type of `p` is `some_complex_struct *` rather than `int *`, the advice would still apply. The assignment operator works. Use it in preference to `memcpy` where it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think `gcc` is indeed confused by the `int*` being cast to a `void*` in the call to `memcpy` and assumes the worst for such a pointer. It could have tried to see if the underlying pointer is properly aligned. Did you try higher optimization levels? It may be that at higher levels `gcc` becomes smarter.

It is also possible that `gcc` doesn't guarantee alignment of `int` pointers in all its code, but that would be unwise and is unlikely.

The compiler is allowed to assume correct alignment of `int*p` because of clause 6.2.3.2 ad 7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned 68) for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Note 68) is about transitivity of being correctly aligned.

Comment: I compiled with `-O2` and `-O3`, so it is probably not lack of optimization. The problem is probably that gcc does not have machinery to deduce pointer alignment for builtins.

Answer (score 1):

If your linux kernel version before to 2.6.28. GCC will throw this `Warning`.
`-munaligned-access` supports the accesses memory on unaligned addresses. This requires the kernel of those systems to enable such accesses Alternatively, unaligned accesses are not supported, all code has to be compiled with -mno-unaligned-access. Upstream Linux kernel releases have automatically and unconditionally supported unaligned accesses as emitted by GCC  due to this option being active since version 2.6.28.

Comment: I guess he means `warning` and not `error`.  Note, that the 2.6.28+ kernels will have an `alignment trap` for processors which don't support un-aligned loads/stores and this will be 1000s of instructions versus 1-3 cycles if aligned.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with, implementing a couple of alternatives for data field access:

```
// #define USE_MEMCPY
// #define USE_PACKED
#ifdef __cplusplus
template <typename T> void SET(T *__attribute__((may_alias)) p, T val) {
    *p=val;
}
template <typename T> T GET(T *__attribute__((may_alias)) p) {
    return *p;
}
#else
#ifdef USE_MEMCPY
#include <string.h>
#define _SET(p,val,line) \
  ({ typeof(val) _temp_##line = (val); \
       memcpy((void*)(p),(void*)&_temp_##line,sizeof(_temp_##line)); }) 
#define _GET(p,line) \
  ({ typeof(*(p)) _temp_##line; \
       memcpy((void*)&_temp_##line,(void*)(p),sizeof(_temp_##line)); \
       _temp_##line; })

#define SET(p,val) _SET(p,val,__LINE__)
#define GET(p) _GET(p,__LINE__)
#else /* no memcpy */
#ifdef USE_PACKED
#define SET(p,val) (((struct { typeof(val) x __attribute__((packed)); } __attribute__((may_alias))*)p)->x=(val))
#define GET(p) (((struct { typeof(*p) x __attribute__((packed)); } __attribute__((may_alias))*)p)->x)
#else
#define SET(p,val) (*((typeof(val) __attribute__((may_alias))*)p)=(val))
#define GET(p) (*((typeof(*p) __attribute__((may_alias))*)p))
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

Then I can write the function like this:

```
int q(int *p) {
    SET(p,GET(p)+12);
    return p[0];
}
```

Comment: You also probably need aligned(1), like `__attribute__((may_alias, aligned(1)))`, to tell the compiler the type is under-aligned as well as possibly aliasing.  You should be able to `typedef int __attribute__((may_alias, aligned(1))) unaligned_int;`